# The view producer.pfviews.podcastsetup didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am creating a podcast management website where you have to register a user w/ django redux registration and provide a username, email & password. When thats done, it takes them straight to a dashboard where they can setup their podcast. When they are going to set it up, I want them to provide me with a `company_name`, `first_name` and `last_name` and save it. This is how my views is set up for it:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.shortcuts import render

from .forms import PodcastSetupForm

from .models import Client

def podcastsetup(request):

    title = 'Podcast Setup'
    title_align_center = True
    form = PodcastSetupForm(request.POST or None)
    context = {
        "title": title,
        "form": form
    }

    if form.is_valid():

        instance = form.save(commit=False)

        company_name = form.cleaned_data.get("company_name")
        first_name = form.cleaned_data.get("first_name")
        last_name = form.cleaned_data.get("last_name")

        instance.company_name = company_name
        instance.first_name = first_name
        instance.last_name = last_name

        instance.save()

        return render(request, "forms.html", context)
```

When I try to get in the website **(http://xxx/podcastsetup/)**, I get the following error:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://xxx/podcastsetup/

Django Version: 1.9
Python Version: 2.7.6
Installed Applications:
('producer',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'registration',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django_extensions',
 'randomslugfield',
 'adminsortable2',
 'crispy_forms')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware')



Traceback:

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  158.                                  % (callback.__module__, view_name))

Exception Type: ValueError at /podcastsetup/
Exception Value: The view producer.pfviews.podcastsetup didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
```

This is what I have in my **forms.py**:

```
from django import forms

from .models import Client

class PodcastSetupForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:

        model = Client
        fields = ['company_name', 'first_name', 'last_name']

    def clean_company_name(self):
        company_name = self.cleaned_data.get('company_name')

        return company_name

    def clean_first_name(self):
        first_name = self.cleaned_data.get('first_name')

        return first_name

    def clean_last_name(self):
        last_name = self.cleaned_data.get('last_name')

        return last_name
```

My **urls.py**:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls.static import static

admin.site.site_header = 'FullCast Admin'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^', include('producer.urls')),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.default.urls')),
    url(r'^dashboard/', 'producer.pfviews.dashboard', name="dashboard"),
    url(r'^podcastsetup/', 'producer.pfviews.podcastsetup', name="podcastsetup"),
]

urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

And the `Client` class in **models.py**:

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from django.utils.encoding import smart_text
from producer import myFields
from randomslugfield import RandomSlugField
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Client(TimeStampedModel):
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    email = models.EmailField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def full_name(self):
        return smart_text('%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name))

    def __unicode__(self):
        return smart_text(self.company_name)
```

Would appreciate some help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def podcastsetup(request):

    title = 'Podcast Setup'
    title_align_center = True
    form = PodcastSetupForm(request.POST or None)
    context = {
        "title": title,
        "form": form
    }

    if form.is_valid():

        instance = form.save(commit=False)

        company_name = form.cleaned_data.get("company_name")
        first_name = form.cleaned_data.get("first_name")
        last_name = form.cleaned_data.get("last_name")

        instance.company_name = company_name
        instance.first_name = first_name
        instance.last_name = last_name

        instance.save()

        return render(request, "forms.html", context)
    else:
        return render(request, "forms.html", context)
```

Try this, you need to return a response even if the form is not valid.